# Store function return value into variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress plugin for custom fields.

```
the_field('something')
```

is, I pressume, just echoing the return value.

Is it not possible to store that return value into a variable?

because `$a = the_field('something');` is also echoing.

What I really want to do is this

```
if(the_field('something')) { 
     // echo the_field('something')
}
else
    // do something
```

but either way, it just echoes that thing in the page

Comment: If a function just echos something, then there is no return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress I do not like.  It seems that they have two functions (or more) for retrieving about anything.  One echos it `the_title()` and the other returns it `get_title()`.  For this plugin this should work:

```
if($field = get_field('something')) { 
     echo $field;
}
else
    // do something
}
```

If you run across something that echos and doesn't return a value and no corresponding function that does return something, then:

```
ob_start();
the_something();
$output = ob_get_clean();
// use $output
```

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, If a function just echos something, then there is no return value. But there is still a way to capture the output.

Consider this function

```
function doStuff()
{
  echo 'hello';
}
```

You can't get a return value from that, but you can capture the contents by using the ob_functions:

```
ob_start();
doStuff();
$output = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean();
```

Now `$output` contains the output of that function, rather than it having been printed.